# Error handling for zipped observables

Tags: rx-java

My use case is: I get a list of permalinks, and need to issue two REST requests per permalink to get their data in parts. When both requests are back, I want to merge their info together and do something with it (here - print it out). I want to do it with code using the `zip` operator. Here is my current code (together with mocks for the library I'm using):

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ContentManager cm = new ContentManager();

        Observable
                .from(cm.getPermalinks(10))
                .flatMap(permalink -> Observable.zip(
                        Observable.<Content>create(subscriber -> cm.getDataByPermalink(permalink, new SubscribingRestCallback(subscriber))),
                        Observable.<Content>create(subscriber -> cm.getStreamByPermalink(permalink, new SubscribingRestCallback(subscriber))),
                        (dataContent, streamUrlContent) -> {
                            if (dataContent == null || streamUrlContent == null) {
                                System.err.println("not zipping " + dataContent + " and " + streamUrlContent);
                                return Observable.empty();
                            }

                            return new Content(dataContent.permalink, dataContent.logoUrl, streamUrlContent.streamUrl);
                        }))
                .subscribe(System.out::println);
    }
}

class SubscribingRestCallback implements RestCallback {

    private final Subscriber<? super Content> subscriber;

    public SubscribingRestCallback(Subscriber<? super Content> subscriber) {
        this.subscriber = subscriber;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Content content) {
        subscriber.onNext(content);
        subscriber.onCompleted();
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(int code, String message) {
        System.err.println(message);
        subscriber.onNext(null);
        subscriber.onCompleted();
    }
}

public class Content {

    public final String permalink;

    public final String logoUrl;

    public final String streamUrl;

    public Content(String permalink, String logoUrl, String streamUrl) {
        this.permalink = permalink;
        this.logoUrl = logoUrl;
        this.streamUrl = streamUrl;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("Content [%s, %s, %s]", permalink, logoUrl, streamUrl);
    }
}

public interface RestCallback {

    void onSuccess(Content content);

    void onFailure(int code, String message);
}

class ContentManager {

    private final Random random = new Random();

    public List<String> getPermalinks(int n) {
        List<String> permalinks = new ArrayList<>(n);
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
            permalinks.add("perma_" + i);
        }

        return permalinks;
    }

    public void getDataByPermalink(String permalink, RestCallback callback) {
        getByPermalink(permalink, callback, false);
    }

    public void getStreamByPermalink(String permalink, RestCallback callback) {
        getByPermalink(permalink, callback, true);
    }

    private void getByPermalink(String permalink, RestCallback callback, boolean stream) {
        // simulate network latency and unordered results
        new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(random.nextInt(1000) + 200);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (random.nextInt(100) < 95) {
                String logoUrl;
                String streamUrl;
                if (stream) {
                    logoUrl = null;
                    streamUrl = "http://" + permalink + "/stream";
                } else {
                    logoUrl = "http://" + permalink + "/logo.png";
                    streamUrl = null;
                }
                callback.onSuccess(new Content(permalink, logoUrl, streamUrl));
            } else {
                callback.onFailure(-1, permalink + " data failure");
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

In general, it works, but I don't like the error handling in this implementation. Basically, the REST requests may fail, in which case the `onFailure` method calls `subscriber.onNext(null)` so that the `zip` method always has something to work with (one request may have failed, but the other one may have not, and I don't know which failed). Then, in the `zip` function I need an `if` which checks that both are not `null` (my code will crash if any of the partial `Content`s is `null`).

I would like to be able to filter out the `null` using the `filter` operator somewhere, if possible. Or maybe there is a better way than emitting `null` values for the failure case but so that it still works with the `zip` function?

Comment: Why do you call `subscriber.onNext(null)` from `onFailure` method? You are supposed to call `subscriber.onError(throwable)` in this case.

Comment: Because calling `onError()` will fail the whole stream, and I don't want this. I want to collect as many results as possible, and basically ignore/filter out the failures. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Even if you don't want the whole stream to fail, you still need to call a `subscriber.onError()` method. There are some other ways to shallow the errors. One of them is an `onErrorResumeNext` operator. Here is an example how to use it - https://gist.github.com/nsk-mironov/3270b103fc3326a325e2.

Comment: Thank you for the snippet. So, when any of the `Observables` which are zipped fails, `zip` fails as well; when it fails, it just says it doesn't want to explode or anything, but rather replace the failed (1-element) `Observable` with an empty one, and this empty one is then returned to `flatMap` - is this correct?

Comment: Yeah, it works just like you've described.

Comment: I have one last question: if you notice my zipper functions, I return `Observable.empty()` if the two objects cannot be zipped, and once I return `Content`. This seems wrong. How should I handle such error conditions in the zipper function?

Comment: BTW, if you make an answer out of your comments I will be able to mark it resolved.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, the right way to notify a `Subscriber` about an error is to call `subscriber.onError` method:

```
class SubscribingRestCallback implements RestCallback {
    private final Subscriber<? super Content> subscriber;

    public SubscribingRestCallback(Subscriber<? super Content> subscriber) {
        this.subscriber = subscriber;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Content content) {
        subscriber.onNext(content);
        subscriber.onCompleted();
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(int code, String message) {
        subscriber.onError(new Exception(message));
    }
}
```

Even if you don't want the whole stream to fail, you still need to call a `subscriber.onError()` method. There are some other ways to shallow the errors. One of them is an `onErrorResumeNext` operator:

```
Observable
        .from(cm.getPermalinks(10))
        .flatMap(permalink -> Observable.zip(
                Observable.<Content>create(subscriber -> cm.getDataByPermalink(permalink, new SubscribingRestCallback(subscriber))),
                Observable.<Content>create(subscriber -> cm.getStreamByPermalink(permalink, new SubscribingRestCallback(subscriber))),
                (dataContent, streamUrlContent) -> {
                    return new Content(dataContent.permalink, dataContent.logoUrl, streamUrlContent.streamUrl);
                }).onErrorResumeNext(Observable.empty()))
        .subscribe(System.out::println);
```

**EDIT**

> I have one last question: if you notice my zipper functions, I return
>   Observable.empty() if the two objects cannot be zipped, and once I
>   return Content. This seems wrong. How should I handle such error
>   conditions in the zipper function?

Yes, returning `Observable.empty()` is totally wrong. Throwing an exception from `zip` function seems like the best solution:

```
Observable
        .from(cm.getPermalinks(10))
        .flatMap(permalink -> Observable.zip(
                Observable.<Content>create(subscriber -> cm.getDataByPermalink(permalink, new SubscribingRestCallback(subscriber))),
                Observable.<Content>create(subscriber -> cm.getStreamByPermalink(permalink, new SubscribingRestCallback(subscriber))),
                (dataContent, streamUrlContent) -> {
                    if (!isDataValid(dataContent, streamUrlContent)) {
                        throw new RuntimeException("Something went wrong.");
                    }
                    return new Content(dataContent.permalink, dataContent.logoUrl, streamUrlContent.streamUrl);
                }).onErrorResumeNext(Observable.empty()))
        .subscribe(System.out::println);
```

Comment: What I eventually did was: the `RestCallback#onFailure()` methods call `subscriber.onError()`, and in the `RestCallback#onSuccess()` I either call `onNext()` and `onComplete()` if the content is valid, or `onError()` if not. Then, the `onResumeNext()` applied to the zipped `Observable` deals with these kind of content errors as well, and my zipping function is as simple as `(dataContent, streamUrlContent) -> new Content(dataContent.permalink, dataContent.logoUrl, streamUrlContent.streamUrl))`. I added the `doOnError()` call to additionally log. I like the code now. Thanks for your help.