# How to create 2 or two parallel network requests with RxJava2?

Tags: android, rx-java, retrofit2, rx-java2

I have created two different API requests with Retrofit 2.0  as

```
Observable<T> getOrganisationList()
Observable<T> getStaffList()
```

I am using `CompositeDisposable` container that contains multiple other disposables. I want the above two observable requests to be executed in parallel.

**Please, answer the question with the help of the code and not with theory only.**

Comment: `Flowable.parallel` or `flatMap`

Comment: @DeanXu Are you suggesting to choose from  Flowable.parallel or flatMap?

Answer (score 5):

Personally, I did it this way (not sure it's the best way to do it though):

```
public void getEventsComingAndPassed(final Context context, Integer id_user){

    Observable<List<Event>> eventsComingObservable = service
            .getEventsComing(id_user)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());

    Observable<List<Event>> eventsPassedObservable = service
            .getEventsPassed(id_user)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());

    Observable<NetResponseGetObservableEventsJSON> combined =
            Observable.zip(eventsComingObservable, eventsPassedObservable, new Func2<List<Event>, List<Event>, NetResponseGetObservableEventsJSON>() {
        @Override
        public NetResponseGetObservableEventsJSON call(List<Event> eventsComing, List<Event> eventsPassed) {
            return new NetResponseGetObservableEventsJSON(eventsComing, eventsPassed);
        }
    });

    combined.subscribe(new NetResponseGetObservableEvents(context));
}
```

Here you can put your two services that will be executed in parallel.
I used the zip operator to do it, for more informations you can check the official [documentation](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/zip.html).

NetResponseGetObserbableEventJSON is a class that contains the 2 lists of events in my case:

```
public class NetResponseGetObservableEventsJSON {

List<Event> eventsComing;
List<Event> eventsPassed;

public NetResponseGetObservableEventsJSON(List<Event> eventsComing, List<Event> eventsPassed) {
    this.eventsComing = eventsComing;
    this.eventsPassed = eventsPassed;
}

public List<Event> getEventsComing() {
    return eventsComing;
}

public void setEventsComing(List<Event> eventsComing) {
    this.eventsComing = eventsComing;
}

public List<Event> getEventsPassed() {
    return eventsPassed;
}

public void setEventsPassed(List<Event> eventsPassed) {
    this.eventsPassed = eventsPassed;
}}
```

And finally I have the Subscriber class in which you can handle the response when both services are done:

```
public class NetResponseGetObservableEvents extends Subscriber<NetResponseGetObservableEventsJSON> {

private Context context;

public NetResponseGetObservableEvents(Context context){

}

@Override
public void onCompleted() {

}

@Override
public void onError(Throwable e) {

}

@Override
public void onNext(NetResponseGetObservableEventsJSON response) {

}}
```

Hope it helps.
And if someone knows a better and proper way to do it I'm interested!

Comment: Thankyou @Anthony Fillion-Maillet What happens if eventsComingObservable or eventsPassedObservable throws JsonException? Would any of the other request be still executed?

Comment: I think this may helps you and answer your questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30822627/error-handling-for-zipped-observables

Comment: I am up voting this as this answer helped me to some extent in guiding.